# Referring to non-final fields of an enclosing class inside an anonymous inner class in Java

Tags: java, closures, anonymous-types, anonymous-class

In Java, I know that it is possible to do something like this:

```
public class Greeter {
    public void greetEventually() {
        final String greeting = "Hello!";
        Job j = new Job() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(greeting);
            }
        };
        j.schedule();
    }
}
```

This would execute the anonymous `Job` at some point in the future. This works because anonymous classes are allowed to refer to final variables in the enclosing scope.

What I'm not sure about is the following case:

```
public class Greeter {
    private String greeting;

    // ... Other methods that might mutate greeting ...

    public void greetEventually() {
        Job j = new Job() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(greeting);
            }
        };
        j.schedule();
    }
}
```

In this case my anonymous `Job` is referring to a non-final field of the enclosing class. When the Job runs, will I see the value of the `greeting` field as it was when the Job was created, or as it is when it is executing? I think I know the answer, but I thought it was an interesting question, and at first it left me and a couple of coworkers second-guessing ourselves for a few minutes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll see the value of `greeting` as it is when the anonymous `Job` executes.

The `final` modifier is required only for local variables, not member variables.

Comment: This is how I suspected it worked.

By the way, the only reason I explicitly mentioned **non-final** fields is because if the field is final the behavior is clear.

Comment: Yup. We thought it would be a good question to have on record in SO. Mike you should accept this one.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the field through (the outer) `this`). You can think of `this` as effectively a `final` local variable. Only the local is `final`, the object pointed to is not (necessarily) constant. Imagine a local variable with the same value as `this` and it should be clear.

```
public class Greeter {
    private String greeting;

    // ... Other methods that might mutate greeting ...

    public void greetEventually() {

        private final Greeter greeter = this; // <---

        Job j = new Job() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(   greeter.greeting   ); // <---
            }
        };
        j.schedule();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The final modifier is applied to the local variables only to provide variables for each instance of the inner class, so we use:
final String greeting;

When you need only one instance of the variable (like the case of constants or common resources), use:
private String greeting;